# Ease Out Cubic - Function Arguments Explanation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, animation

On this great [web page](http://gizma.com/easing/#cub2) I found a list of easing algorithms that can add nice visual appeal to my webpages.

Despite, I found there brief mention of the function arguments (see below), the algorithm does not behave as I would wish. Can I kindly ask for explanation on what values/ranges should be entered into the arguments of the function below mentioned?

*Argument list:*

- **t: current time** - should here be values 0...1, or real number of the current frame?
- **b: start value** - I assume, a start X or Y coordinate of the object being moved
- **c: change in value** - can here be number 1 all the time for all the frames?
- **d: duration** - the number of frames altogether?

`Math.easeOutCubic = function (t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d;
    t--;
    return c*(t*t*t + 1) + b;
};`

Should the values be incrementally added to the last value obtained from the function, or should they be added to the initial 0 position?

Comment: This link explains my question in pretty detail: http://upshots.org/actionscript/jsas-understanding-easing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're right, `d` is for duration and `t` is current time. Therefore, `t` should be from `0` to `d`.

`c` is a total change, should be equal to `end value` - `start value`.

- For `t = 0` we have `c*(-1 + 1) + b` or `b`
- For `t = d` we have `c*(0 + 1) + b` or `b + c`

Function would be the same for any fps, it's up to you how frequently update position and call the function.

Comment: +1, hi and thanks for your repply. I will try the formula with new information when I get home. **Can b(start value) be a negative number too?** Say, if I wish to move the object from out of the screen, which means from -50y to 250y. I am not sure if the formula will work in that way too.

Comment: Yes. Only if you'll change `t` from 0 to some negative value, it will work not the way intended.

Comment: I can confirm, that after correct understanding of the function arguments, the 2d objects behave as they really should with ease implemented. I am therefore identifying your answer as the *Accepted Answer*.